# Video and Song Streamming website development

Tags: web, streaming, hosting

Guys I need your help here,

I got a new project in PHP to make a website, basic functionality will be : admin can upload songs and videos from backend. Frontend will display songs and videos, categories and other music related stuffs. I ll be using CI or CakePHP but my main concern is about hosting. Traffic will be 5K users per day. Now what is the best hosting solution, where users will stream songs and videos online. Do I need to buy dedicated server or cloud or VPS will do?

Also if you have made this kind of website then suggest me some guidlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a daily 5K users, it will always be better to go for dedicated as it is a server solely for you. So if tomorrow the number of viewers increase you wouldn't have to face any slow loading times (as in cloudhosting) and create a bad impression for users who would also leave your site and not return.

Comment: which dedicated server you suggest?

Comment: I guess iWeb looks very attractive. But actually the costs of these are too high, especially $79 - $99, else its best if you incur a one time cost to purchase a server and go getting to install it even though it would cost a little more than $200 because paying almost $100 a month for a year can get you a server that you can control at home just paying only for the bandwidth.